# Is there any functional difference between `should be_invalid` and `should_not be_valid`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec

Both invokations ensure that a model isn't valid.

Is there any functional difference? Is there a prevailing best practice between the two?

Answer (score 2):

There is no magic in rspec `be_...` matchers. If the matcher is not defined in rspec it just invokes whatever method name goes after `be_` with `?` sign. So `be_valid` invokes method `valid?` defined in 'activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb' and 'be_invalid' invokes `invalid?` defined in  'activemodel/lib/active_model/validations.rb'. Here is the source code of the latter:

```
def invalid?(context = nil)
  !valid?(context)
end
```

So I guess the answer is probably no.

Answer (score 0):

No functional difference I'm aware of.

The "best practice" is to use whatever is the most readable and communicative given the spec.

Answer (score 0):

Just an 'icing' for a developer :) Same as:

```
flag = true

if not flag
  ...
end

unless flag
  ...
end
```